# Dynamic Query w/ Quotes issue

Tags: t-sql, dynamicquery

I'm trying to write a dynamic query that produces the same results as the following, but replaces the fixed tablename with a variable.

```
    SELECT *
    WHERE tableName = 'Table2A'
```

works fine but

```
    DECLARE @tablename AS NVARCHAR(100)
    SET @tablename = N'Table2A'
    DECLARE @execquery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @execquery = N'
       SELECT *
       WHERE tableName = ''' + QUOTENAME(@tablename) + N''''    

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @execquery
```

returns no records.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the fact that your SQL statement is invalid, QUOTENAME() simply places brackets "[]" around the supplied variable.  Replace the EXECUTE statement with a PRINT statement, and you'll get the following results:

```
DECLARE @tablename AS NVARCHAR(100)
    SET @tablename = N'Table2A'
    DECLARE @execquery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @execquery = N'
       SELECT *
       WHERE tableName = ''' + QUOTENAME(@tablename) + N''''    
PRINT @execquery
    --EXECUTE sp_executesql @execquery
```

RESULTS:

```
   SELECT *
   WHERE tableName = '[Table2A]'
```

Comment: Thanks! Good tip on the PRINT technique, I'll use that a lot.